# 2D screenspace zooming

Tags: perl, graphics, screen, 2d, zooming

I need to draw 2D lines on perl into image of size 1024x768; Coordinates of lines are unix timestamps like x1=1365693813 y1=(some virtual center) x2=1365793815 y2=(some virtual center). What the formula to zoom real life coords into image space?

Comment: you need to know a maximum of `x` and `y` coordinates

Comment: after that just take a fraction: `x_max = 1024, your_timestamp = x` => `x = 1024/x_max * your_timestamp`

Comment: seems more like pan than zoom? But in general you want to map from one 2D space to another, you need full descriptions of both spaces. The full description of the image space is easy. The full description of your "view window" (i.e. the limits of what you want to show on the image from all possible times and values of y2) is missing. Define that, and it will be simple to provide you an answer!

Comment: Oh, I guess unless your `x1, y1` and `y2, y2` define the corners of your view window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `($x1,$y1)` and `($x2,$y2)` define your bottom left and top right corners of a "view window" and you have a point you wish to plot `($x3,$y3)` where `$x1 <= $x3 <= $x2` and `$y1 <= $y3 <= $y2`. Also assuming you are working in a standard image space where (0,0) is the top left corner of the image. You can find `($xp, $yp)` as the pixel co-ordinates to plot on the image like this:

```
# View window
my ($x1,$y1) = (1365693813, 100);
my ($x2,$y2) = (1365693815, 200);
my ($vw ,$vh) = ( $x2 - $1, $y2 - $y1 );

# Image width/height
my ($imgw,$imgh) = (1024, 768);

# Point to plot in original co-ordinates
my ($x3,$y3) = (1365693814, 150);

# Calculate point to plot in image co-ordinates
my $xp = int( ( $imgw * ($x3 - $x1)/$vw) + 0.5 );
my $yp = int( ( $imgh * ( 1.0 - ($y3 - $y1)/$vh) ) + 0.5 );

# Now plot ( $xp, $yp ), provided it is inside the graphic!
```